# Can't disabled Debug and mime messages

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, struts2

I'm working on a web application using maven, Struts 2 and Spring IoC and Security and I get a lot of debug messages and mime messages like these bellow :

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>crt</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-x509-ca-cert</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>cbt</extension>
    <mime-type>application/x-cbr</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
```

and these messages made my application very slow
Can anybody help me please ?

Comment: where are you seeing this messages ? Please don't answer "in the log"

Comment: in the eclipse console, when I click on some pages for example addEmployee.jsp

Comment: @AndreaLigios: And he/she didn't. ;)

Comment: @AbdessamadBoutgayout: Show a little more of this messages.

Comment: @AleksandrM Meh, I've seen it coming... :D